# Circular dependencies error in Spring when using self autowiring feature

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ioc-container

I'm using spring boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE (one of the latest ones) with this code:

```
@Service
public class AService {

private AService aService; //Self autowire

public AService(AService aService){
    this.aService = aService;
}

@Cacheable(value = "aCacheName")
public List<SomeClass> expensiveOperation(){
    //Very expensive operation that can be cached
}

public List<SomeClass> otherOperation(){
    return aService.expensiveOperation().otherOperation()); //Call proxy, can't use this.expensiveOperation() because it will bypass the cache
}
}
```

I'm getting this error:

"The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle."

I know that Spring allows "Self autowiring", what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the real solution here is that this needs to be 2 different services, one with expensiveOperation, and one with otherOperation. The 2nd service depends on the 1st and the 2nd can even delegate methods to the 1st if you ultimately want a single interface to the rest of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what is wrong with `this` ?? Also you could mark it as @Lazy and use field autowire or ever setter insteed of constructor. You wont be able to do it with constructor IMHO as you will never be able to provide instance for construction.

Comment: If you call "this"it will run expensiveOperation() again, that is under @Cacheable.

Comment: You can always inject application context and get and get your bean. You can even do the assignment in @PostConstruct as at this point all beans should be injectable.